# How to remove dot "." after the numerical values in Excel data file?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

in my data sheet, there are string variables. How can I remove that? When I import file in the SPSS software, the values show full stop after the digit ".". Kindly guide me to remove that.

[image]

Comment: Does the actual cell in excel show the . too and does it actually contain a . if you look in the formula bar?

Comment: no in the excel file cannot see, but when import in the SPSS it shows "." and on running any analysis it gives error

Comment: So that means the problem is with the SPSS import, not with excel.

Comment: But I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Contact the people behind SPSS.

Comment: I don't know SPSS but could this be the decimal point if the cell is numeric rather than text when it's imported?

Comment: Ill try to take help from some SPSS people, however after even changing the cell format still it has the same issue. Thanks for the guidance

Answer (score 1):

Easy to solve. Go to variable view. click on Type. Change from numeric to string and the dots will disappear. The missing values in your output will also disappear. Don't ask me why this works because I cannot tell you. It simply worked in my data set and output. It makes no sense because string variables are supposed to be letters and not numbers. However it worked. As a pragmatic individual I am ok with it and moving on.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is kept as strings I think it's just a matter of selecting the cells clicking "ctrl+H" (replace).

In the "Find" field input "." and leave the "replace with" field empty.
Click "Replace all".

That's it.

Comment: I tried that now, but search results show nothing with this error "Microsoft office excel cannot find the data you're searching for".  if you can look at the image I shared from SPSS file. you can see there is dot after numbers

Answer (score 0):

Removing "dot" in excel after typing numbers and automatically appearing. Be sure uncheck the option from the excel. Click file>option>Advance ( Editing option) uncheck the " Automatically insert a decimal point.....that's it.